# Merge multiple ASCII files into single GeoTIFF file with multiple bands

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff-tiff, esri-ascii-raster

Is there a way to combine multiple ASCII (text) files into a single TIFF file with multiple bands (Band1, Band2 ...) using GDAL or Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the GDAL command line tools:

```
gdalbuildvrt -separate out.vrt b1.asc b2.asc b3.asc
gdal_translate out.vrt out.tif
```